# Need to search multiple words using linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I have a requirement where user comes and enters a search words based on that i need to query it using linq and display the records. Eg goes here:

Search Eg 1: "Infosys" if user enters infosys as search term i can use contains and get the result easily.

Eg 2: "Tata Consultancy Services" If user enters this i can still use contains and get the record easily. But the catch is what if the user enters just "Tata Services" or a grammitical mistake as "Tata constult service" Still i want to show the records which consists of any of the 3 words. Either Tata/Consutult/Service.

This search is a dynamic and not restricted to 3 it will be an array. I can split the words by Space.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `Any` extension method:

```
string queryString = "Tata Services";
var queryParts = queryString.Split(' ');
var result = Records.Where(r => queryParts.Any(p => r.Name.Contains(p)));
```